# Java plugin - SonarQube Add Custom Rule

Tags: java, sonarqube

As mentioned in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455209/sonarqube-java-plugin-custom-rule) ,I have followed all the steps and added a TestRule.java in /checks folder.

But when I compile this plugin code I get following error :

```
17:02:52.614 [main] INFO  o.s.s.j.c.SecurityAnnotationMandatoryCheck - implements Interface : Second
Interface
17:02:52.614 [main] INFO  o.s.s.j.c.SecurityAnnotationMandatoryCheck - Method Name MySecurityAnnotat
ion
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.073 sec - in org.sonar.samples.jav
a.checks.SecurityAnnotationMandatoryCheckTest
Running org.sonar.samples.java.checks.TestRuleTests
17:02:52.617 [Report about progress of Java AST analyzer] INFO  org.sonar.squidbridge.ProgressReport
 - 1/1 source files have been analyzed
Executing *****************************TestRULE...........17:02:52.673 [main] INFO  org.sonar.squidb
ridge.ProgressReport - 1 source files to be analyzed
17:02:52.679 [main] DEBUG o.s.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - ----- Classpath analyzed by Squid:
17:02:52.680 [main] DEBUG o.s.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\dev\JavaPlugin\sonar-examples-master\sonar-examples-master\plugins\java-custom-rules\target\test-jars\commo
ns-collections4-4.0.jar
17:02:52.680 [main] DEBUG o.s.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - C:\Users\dev\Jav
aPlugin\sonar-examples-master\sonar-examples-master\plugins\java-custom-rules\target\test-classes
17:02:52.680 [main] DEBUG o.s.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder - -----
17:02:52.688 [main] DEBUG o.s.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter - Completing symbol : Object
17:02:52.691 [Report about progress of Java AST analyzer] INFO  org.sonar.squidbridge.ProgressReport
 - 1/1 source files have been analyzed
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.04 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.sonar
.samples.java.checks.TestRuleTests
detected(org.sonar.samples.java.checks.TestRuleTests)  Time elapsed: 0.033 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one issue expected
        at org.sonar.samples.java.checks.TestRuleTests.detected(TestRuleTests.java:19)


Results :

Tests in error:
  TestRuleTests.detected:19 ╗ IllegalState At least one issue expected

Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.750 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-04T17:02:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/313M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code on org.sonar.samples.java.checks.TestRuleTests.detected(TestRuleTests.java:19) is given below :

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.sonar.java.checks.verifier.JavaCheckVerifier;

import java.lang.System;

public class TestRuleTests {

    TestRule check = new TestRule();
    //check.max=100;

    @Test
    public void detected() {
        // Verifies that the check will raise the adequate issues with the expected message.
        // In the test file, lines which should raise an issue have been commented out
        // by using the following syntax: "// Noncompliant {{EXPECTED_MESSAGE}}"
        System.out.print("Executing *****************************TestRULE...........");
        JavaCheckVerifier.verify("src/test/files/TestRule.java", check); //Line number 19,this line is indicated in error
        System.out.print("After Executing *****************************TestRULE...........");
    }
}
```

How can I add issue ?

Comment: Did you actually read the comment in the test files where the test is failing?

Comment: JavaCheckVerifier.verify("src/test/files/TestRule.java", check); this line is causing error .. i do not understand why.. ..please provide some inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error : an issue is expected in the file you are testing.

So in "src/test/files/TestRule.java" an issue should be raised by your rule and checked by using the comment : // Noncompliant as specified in the comment in your test class.

If you have absolutely no issue raised by your check then you should use the method `verifyNoIssue` to avoid the error.